# Batch dislikes some characters I want to write to a file

Tags: batch-file

Apparently some characters in my script are invalid, and instead of writing the content to the file, the Batch Application simply echoes everything out to the console and creates no file. Is there a way to make it ignore ANY character between the brackets? I had to remove all dots just to avoid getting ". was unexpected at this time."

```
:create
echo.
echo  Creating config...
SET "inpath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo\cfg"
echo  Writing to:
echo  %inpath%\RGBUI.cfg
(
@echo // You may customize the key binds here
@echo bind "k" "incrementvar cl_hud_color 1 8 1;incrementvar cl_draw_only_deathnotices 0 1 1"
@echo bind "KP_END" "cl_hud_color 1;incrementvar cl_draw_only_deathnotices 0 1 1"
@echo bind "KP_DOWNARROW" "cl_hud_color 2;incrementvar cl_draw_only_deathnotices 0 1 1"
@echo bind "KP_PGDN" "cl_hud_color 3;incrementvar cl_draw_only_deathnotices 0 1 1"
@echo bind "KP_LEFTARROW" "cl_hud_color 4;incrementvar cl_draw_only_deathnotices 0 1 1"
@echo bind "KP_5" "cl_hud_color 5;incrementvar cl_draw_only_deathnotices 0 1 1"
@echo bind "KP_RIGHTARROW" "cl_hud_color 6;incrementvar cl_draw_only_deathnotices 0 1 1"
@echo bind "KP_HOME" "cl_hud_color 7;incrementvar cl_draw_only_deathnotices 0 1 1"
@echo bind "KP_UPARROW" "cl_hud_color UPARROW;incrementvar cl_draw_only_deathnotices 0 1 1"
@echo echo 
@echo echo 
@echo echo DarkMesa's RGBUI is now loaded.
@echo echo Use NumPad keys to change GUI color
@echo echo or K to scroll through them (doubleclick)
@echo ehco 
@echo echo You are using version 1.0 - Updates might
@echo echo be available, Check the Official Guide
@echo echo to find out
@echo echo 
@echo echo You may contact me on my Steam Profile:
@echo echo http://steamcommunity.com/id/darkmesah/
@echo echo 
@echo echo 
) >"%inpath%\RGBUI.cfg"
```

Comment: @KenWhite, I am not sure how that would be the problem.  That is the accepted form for protecting special characters and white space.  I never assign quotes to my variables.  I always put quotes around them when using them.

Comment: @KenWhite Didn't change anything. I don't think the problem is in the path.

Comment: You need to escape all of your right parentheses.  As it thinks you are closing the code block.

Comment: @Squashman I checked multiple times and the parentheses appear to all open and close correctly.

Comment: You need to escape the right parentheses in this line of code: `@echo echo or K to scroll through them (doubleclick)`.  It is closing the code block!

Comment: @Squashman I noticed that just a few Minutes ago, thanks for the Help, I apologize as this was a pretty banal mistake and wasn't worth a thread dedicated to it, I simply should have checked my code better or have never performed that Mistake in the first place.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I stand corrected (by both you and squashman :-) ). I've cleaned up the comment clutter. Thanks to both of you.